# Powershell command to kill multiple processes at once using the processes PID?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, process

I am specifically trying to create an if statement that would be able to terminate these processes.
The example below is just pseudo-code:

```
x = list of processes
if(process in list is named "y" or "z") {
 kill process & return what processes were stopped (possibly a -v flag?)
}
```

Comment: That isn’t valid powershell and you haven’t shown what you’re trying that you need help with.

Answer (score 3):

```
$list = 1, 2, 3
foreach($_pid in $list){
    Stop-Process -Id $_pid
}
```

Comment: perfect, I didnt know I could list them and then iterate through an array like you would in python or js.